# What are blocks useful for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please give a real life example of **how, where and why** to use a `block`.

```
# Block Method
def say_hello(&block)
   puts "hello!"
   block.call
end

say_hello { puts "hello again!" }
  #=> hello!, hello again!

# Standard Method
def say_hello(block)
   puts "hello!"
   puts block
end

say_hello("hello again!")
  #=> hello!, hello again!
```

Obviously this example doesn't do a `block` any justice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: A "real life example"? In Ruby? I can't imagine Ruby code without them, because they are so intrinsic to everything we write. A look at any piece of Ruby code is sure to have multiple examples showing real-life uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of cases where blocks are good candidates.

In some cases blocks are not the only solution as you have seen, you may have probably been able to perform a similar execution without a block. This is the case, for example, of the following ActiveRecord model statement

```
User.create! do |u|
  u.email = "example@example.com"
  u.password = "password"
end
```

Without blocks

```
u = User.new
u.email = "example@example.com"
u.password = "password"
u.save!
```

or

```
u = User.create!(email: "example@example.com", password: "password")
```

Generally speaking, you could say that blocks make the code more concise and readable

```
File.open("file.txt") { |f| f.write("text") }
```

at first glance can be rewritten as

```
f = File.open("file.txt")
f.write("text")
f.close
```

which is indeed more verbose. But there is more. In fact, in the block example the variable `f` is a local block variable and it's not visible outside the scope. This is one of the first interesting aspects of the blocks: scoping.

But there's even more. One of my favourite usage of blocks is as wrappers. Let's assume you want to execute a block of code that can fail. And when the code fails, you want to release the resources before raising the error. You can use a block

```
def safe
  yield
ensure
  # clean the house
end
```

In fact, this is exactly what the `File.open` does when you pass a block. If the execution is wrapped in a block, in case of failure the method ensures the file handler is closed so that you don't leave open file connections behind.

Another good example is the `Timeout` library.

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes more than 5 seconds...
}
```

If you want to raise an error if an execution does not termine in a reasonable amount of time, you can wrap the code in a block. The block starts a parallel thread that counts the execution time and raises if the code *inside* the block does not ends before the thread ended.

I challenge you to implement the same code without a block. It would definitely be very hard.

Generally speaking, the block allows you to construct a generic skeleton for the method that could be customized even further at runtime by passing a block. These kind of examples (the `Enumerable` methods such as `each`, the `Timeout`, the `Benchmark.ms`, etc) are probably the best examples to understand the power of blocks.

Comment: Mi paisano, grazie! Wonderful explanation, Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
people = ['bob', 'joe', 'ralph']
people.each { |person| puts "Hi, #{person}!" }
```

Comment: What does this mean? Are you saying `each` is a `block method`? Like it is defined somewhere as `def each(&var)...`

Comment: @in-spired: Yes. Don't you see the block being passed? (Although in all likelihood if somebody were implementing it in Ruby it would be defined with `yield` and `block_given?` rather than wrapping the block with the `&block` syntax.)

Comment: @in-spired: Yep.  (Or at least something equivalent to it.) It goes through the array, handing each item in turn to the block.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each

Comment: That's cools so how is `each` actually coded in source? Because I can't say for example: `people.say_hello` Aren't we only allowed to say `say_hello {...}` ?

Comment: Within the Array class, it could be written something like `def each; for item in self; yield item; end; end`

Answer (score 0):

- how:

  ```
  def say_hello(&block)
    name = current_user.name
    res = block.call(name)
    res =+ ". and buy a car"
    raw res
  end

  say_hello do |name|
    "<div class='x1' > #{ name } </div>"
  end

  say_hello do |name|
    "Hi #{name}"
  end

  say_hello do |name|
    if name == 'Jack'
      'U are so ugly'
    else
      name
    end
  end
  ```
- where:
  `say_hello` method defined in `Rails helper`
  used in `Rails views`
- why:
  flexibility, you don't have create new methods to only change formatting and creating a bulk of crappy methods (say_hello, say_hello_for_jack, say_hello_with_html...)

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the insight. Starting to make sense now! :)